# How to retrieve Friendy URL from Term-Driven Page with SP PnP JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, taxonomy, term-set, pnpjs

With this piece of code, I get the properties of all terms of termset. I'd like to get the **Friendly URL** also.

```
  terms.get().then((terms:ITerm[])=>{
            terms.forEach((term:any)=>{
              term.LocalCustomProperties._Sys_Nav_TargetUrl;
              console.log(term.LocalCustomProperties._Sys_Nav_TargetUrl);
            });
          });
```

I tried : *_Sys_Nav_FriendlyUrlSegment* but that does not work.

---

**Navigation Node Type:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try the below code,

```
 terms.get().then((terms:ITerm[])=>{
            terms.forEach((term:any)=>{
              term.LocalCustomProperties._Sys_Nav_TargetUrl;
              console.log(term.LocalCustomProperties._Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl);
            });
          });
```

The above code gives you the simple link.

AFAIK, `term.LocalCustomProperties` doesn't have the friendly URL property, so you can try the below approach, it will help you to get the friendly URL using JSOM, but not using PnP JS,

To retrieve the friendly URL you could utilize [SP.Publishing.Navigation.NavigationTerm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj994647(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#methods) object which:

> Specifies navigation behavior and properties for a [SP.Taxonomy.Term
>
>   constructor (sp.taxonomy)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj857086(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) object that is used to drive the navigation
>   and friendly URLs for a website.

The specified class contains [getWebRelativeFriendlyUrl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj954464(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) [method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj954464(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which

> returns the friendly URL segments as a concatenated path.

Example

```
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/15";

$.getScript(scriptbase +"/sp.runtime.js",function(){    
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "/sp.js", function() {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "/sp.publishing.js",function(){
            $.getScript(scriptbase+"/sp.taxonomy.js",function(){

                var termId = "--Term ID goes here--";


                var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);

                var term = taxSession.getTerm(termId);
                var navTerm = SP.Publishing.Navigation.NavigationTerm.getAsResolvedByWeb(ctx,term, ctx.get_web(), "CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider");
                var friendlyUrl = navTerm.getWebRelativeFriendlyUrl();

                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                   console.log(friendlyUrl.get_value());
                },
                function(sender,args) {
                   console.log(args.get_message());
                });
            })
        })
    })
});
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957824/sharepoint-2013-term-driven-page-friendly-url-using-jsom/44975925#44975925)

Comment: When I select **Simple Link** in the Navigation Node Type, I can retrieve the Url with __Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl_, but I would like to do than automatically with a **Friendly URL**

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: I would like to use this JSOM script in my webpart, and I have to **register the SharePoint JSOM API as external scripts** like in this [exemple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom#register-the-sharepoint-jsom-api-as-external-scripts) (see _Reference JSOM declaratively_ section). How can I do that?

Comment: Kindly raise this as a new question, so that more people will look at it and give you various approaches.

Comment: if you find my answer useful, kindly upvote and accept it as answer, so that it will help others too.

Comment: Actually, that's not what I was looking for, but I solved the problem another way ... otherwise, I just forgot to upvote ^^'

Comment: How did you solve your problem??

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is to associate each term of my termset to a page of the site, so I need to create a "pageUrl" property for example in the term, and retrieve the link of the page in this property. I always look for the best way to do this. I've given up the idea of the Friendly URL.